# Drawing an overlay on top of an application's window

Tags: qt, paint

I want to be able to paint on top of my application's window so that I can annotate all the widgets with some extra diagnostic information, similar to the CSS developer tools in Firefox (eg add widget classes, styles, highlight borders etc).

I can walk the widget tree and extract the relevant information, but the question is how can I overlay all the application windows with this information?

One way would be to override my `QMainWindow`'s paint event, but this has to be done for all top level windows.  Is there an alternative method where you can paint on the `QDesktopWidget` for instance?  Or any hooks into each `QWidget`'s paint method?  Anything that involves subclassing `QWidget` itself won't work with the standard widgets.

This follows on from my previous question:

- [Are there any useful tools for diagnosing Qt layout and spacing problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419942/are-there-any-useful-tools-for-diagnosing-qt-layout-and-spacing-problems)

cheers
Mandrill

EDIT: 
Thanks to Dmitry I've now got a really simple method that is easily extensible:

```
class DiagnosticStyle : public QWindowsVistaStyle
{
Q_OBJECT

public: 
    typedef QWindowsVistaStyle BaseStyle;
    void drawControl(ControlElement element, const QStyleOption* option, QPainter* painter, const QWidget* widget) const;
};


void DiagnosticStyle::drawControl(ControlElement element, const QStyleOption* option, QPainter* painter, const QWidget* widget) const
{
    BaseStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
    if (widget && painter) {
        // draw a border around the widget
        painter->setPen(QColor("red"));
        painter->drawRect(widget->rect());

        // show the classname of the widget
        QBrush translucentBrush(QColor(255,246,240, 100));
        painter->fillRect(widget->rect(), translucentBrush);
        painter->setPen(QColor("darkblue"));
        painter->drawText(widget->rect(), Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter, widget->metaObject()->className()); 
    }
}

qApp->setStyle(new DiagnosticStyle());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create own style class based on QMotifStyle or other ... and paint on any widget/control related to him information.

```
void MyStyle::drawPrimitive(PrimitiveElement element, const QStyleOption *option,QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget) const
{
     QStyle::State flags = option->state;
     QRect      rect     = option->rect;
     QPalette   pal      = option->palette;
     QBrush brush;

    switch (element)
    {
        case PE_FrameTabWidget:
        {
             painter->save();

                 // for example: draw anything on TabWidget
                painter->drawPixmap(rect,centerPm,centerPm.rect());
             painter->restore();
        }
        break;
        default:
         QMotifStyle::drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget);
         break;

    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea -- would it be more useful to override  `QStyle::drawControl()` instead, as that gives you access to the widget?

Comment: Turns out this is exactly what I needed -- see my edited post

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in Qt5 the styles (GTK, Windows, etc) were made internal.  Now you need to use QCommonStyle.

If anyone's wondering how to do this with Qt5+.  Here's a self-contained version of @the_mandrill's code above.

```
class DiagnosticStyle : public QCommonStyle
{
Q_OBJECT

public: 
    typedef QStyle BaseStyle;
    void drawControl(ControlElement element, const QStyleOption* option, QPainter* painter, const QWidget* widget) const
    {
        QCommonStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
        if (widget && painter) {
            // draw a border around the widget
            painter->setPen(QColor("red"));
            painter->drawRect(widget->rect());

            // show the classname of the widget
            QBrush translucentBrush(QColor(255,246,240, 100));
            painter->fillRect(widget->rect(), translucentBrush);
            painter->setPen(QColor("darkblue"));
            painter->drawText(widget->rect(), Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter, widget->metaObject()->className()); 
        }
    };
};
```

Then, in your main window constructor call

```
qApp->setStyle(new DiagnosticStyle());
```